# How can I resize my LUKS partitions on arch?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, filesystems, luks

My Arch installation is on a nvme drive with three partitions: a boot partition, a root partition of 30GB, and a home partition of 1TB. Both the root and home partitions have LUKS encryption. However, I am running out of space on the root partition while installing packages from pacman, so I need to expand it / shrink home. The name of my drive is nvme0n1, with the boot partition labeled as nvme0n1p1, the root partition as nvme0n1p2, and the home partition as nvme0n1p3. How would I go about doing that? If it wasnt LUKS i could easily do it, the encryption layer is what is confusing me significantly. i don't use LVM or anything like that,